# Neural Network - SGD Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

Please see the below Neural Network code for moons dataset (binary classification) which contains two features (x1 and x2) and the task is to predict the class for a given data. I have used Stochastic Gradient descent for updating the weights and the problem is SGD not converging. My predicted value is around 0.9 (small variations) for all training instances. If I increase epoch or learning rate still output shows 1 for every instance.

Possibly I may went wrong in equations. Could anyone help me on this, please?

Thanks in advance.

- No of input layer: 2 + bias
- No of O/p layer: 1
- No of hidden layer: 1
- No of neurons/hidden layer: 3

Code:

```
# Splitting the data for testing and training of neural networks (70 % training data and 30% testing data)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cv.train_test_split(moon[["X0", "X1"]], moon["Class"], test_size=0.30, random_state=50)

# Default value of hidden layer = 1 and neurons per hidden layer = 3 and default value of all bias = 1
# Currently works for only binary classification
class Neural_net():
    def __init__(self, train, target, hidden_layers = 1, neu_hid_layer = 3, bias=1, learning_rate=0.03, epoch=500):
        self.train = train # This is a training data set
        self.target = target # This is target column that needs to be predicted
        self.hidden_layers = hidden_layers # Number of hidden layers choosen usually either 1 or 2
        self.neu_hid_layer = neu_hid_layer # Number of neurons selected in hidden layers
        self.features = list(self.train.columns)
        self.in_layer = len(self.features) # Number of features. In moons data set its 2
        self.hyp_op = None
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate # Default value of learning rate is 0.7
        self.bias = bias
        self.epoch = epoch
        self.predicted = None

        # This decides the number of output layer required for multi classification
        if len(self.target.unique()) == 2:
            self.op_layer = 1
        else:
            self.op_layer = self.target.unique()

        if self.hidden_layers == 1:
            self.wt_ly2 = 2 * np.random.rand(self.neu_hid_layer, self.in_layer) - 1 # 3 rows 2 column matrix
            self.wt_ly3 = 2 * np.random.rand(self.op_layer, self.neu_hid_layer) -1 # 1 row 3 column matrix
            self.bias_ly1 = np.ones(3).reshape(3,1)/2
            self.bias_ly2 = np.array([0.5])
            self.tdelta2 = np.zeros((self.op_layer, self.neu_hid_layer))
            self.tdelta1 = np.zeros((self.neu_hid_layer, self.in_layer))



    def sigmoid(self, z):
        g_z = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
        return g_z


    def sigmoid_derivative(self, sig):
        derivative = np.multiply(sig, (1 - sig))
        return derivative



    def sochastic_gradient_descent(self, td1, td2, tb1,tb2): # Here m is equal to one for SGD
        self.wt_ly2 = self.wt_ly2 - (self.learning_rate * td1)
        self.wt_ly3 = self.wt_ly3 - (self.learning_rate * td2)
        self.bias_ly1 = self.bias_ly1 - (self.learning_rate * tb1)
        self.bias_ly2 = self.bias_ly2 - (self.learning_rate * tb2)


    def propogation(self, instance, cnt): # For single instance in our data set
        a1 = np.array([[instance[1]], [instance[2]]])
        z2 = np.dot(self.wt_ly2, a1) + self.bias_ly1
        a2 = self.sigmoid(z2)
        z3 = np.dot(self.wt_ly3, a2) + self.bias_ly2
        a3 = self.sigmoid(z3)
        out = round(a3[0][0], 8)
        #print(out)

        # Back Propogation
        error = (list(self.target)[cnt] - out)
        #print(error)
        delta3 = error * self.sigmoid_derivative(out)
        delta2 = np.multiply(np.dot(self.wt_ly3.T, delta3), self.sigmoid_derivative(a2))
        tdelta2 = delta3 * a2.T
        tdelta1 = np.dot(delta2, a1.T)
        #print(tdelta1)
        #print(tdelta2)
        tb1 = delta2
        tb2 = delta3
        #print(tdelta2)
        if delta3 <=0:
            self.sochastic_gradient_descent(tdelta1, tdelta2, tb1, tb2)

        return out


    def train_NN(self):
        TRMSE = []
        for ep in range(self.epoch):
            pred = []
            cnt = 0
            for row in self.train.itertuples():
                pred.append(self.propogation(row, cnt))
                cnt = cnt + 1
            self.predicted = pred
            error = np.subtract(np.array(self.target), np.array(self.predicted))
            RMSE = np.sqrt(np.square(error)/len(self.target))
            TRMSE.append(RMSE)




inst = Neural_net(x_train, y_train)
inst.train_NN()
inst.predicted

Sample o/p: Predicted Value
0.99980247,
 0.99979704000000003,
 0.99981863999999998,
 0.99980820999999998,
 0.99986757000000004,
 0.99980886999999996,
 0.99983409000000001,
 0.99980568000000003,
 0.99980550000000001,
 0.99985767000000003,
 0.99986379000000003,
 0.9997935
```